# How do I make it so this script actually posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var link = " http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/"
var itemType = "shirts"
var id = "ovlutjfac"
fullLink = link + itemType + "/" + id
var size;

function addToCart() {
    var info = {
        'size': 32734,
        'commit': ''
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: fullLink,
        type: 'post',
        data: info
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Successfully added item to cart");
    });
}
addToCart();
```

wont add the item to cart, im trying to make it so if i have a link before a supreme item comes out that i just run this script and it adds it to cart instantly
its for http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/ovlutjfac/black

Comment: This is because your fullLink variable is getting initialized with "http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirtsovlutjfac". You should append '/' between itemType and id using var fullLink = link + itemType + "/" + id

Comment: And once you've fixed the link, you'll notice that it won't work due to CORS

Comment: In order to overcome the CORS issue, you can simply try adding **dataType: 'jsonp'** in your **$.ajax()** request, or else you will have to make changes on the server side Access Control Policy.

Comment: @ShekharChikara still didn't work, how do i fix it via server side access control policy or im not sure if this is even the error?

Comment: Are you sure doing a POST request to your API url http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/ovlutjfac/black with the **info** object sends a JSON response?

Comment: Right now, your API doesn't seem to be properly setup, since when we send a request with the **info** object to the above API url, it returns an HTML response.

Comment: @ShekharChikara can you say what to change/fix cus i have no idea since i havent done this in nearly 2 years

Answer (score 0):

when you specify fullLink, be sure to put a slash in between itemType and id.
currently fullLink is http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirtsovlutjfac

you want to do

```
var fullLink = link + itemType + id;
```

Comment: still wont add to cart